# Python Library for using Windows authentification system

Tags: python, windows

I would like to know if there is any python library to use the windows local  authentification system (local username and password checking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LogonUser` from the `win32security` module to use the credentials you want to check to login.
The function will fail if the credentials are wrong